# Is there a 'Mathematics wiki' analogous to 'String theory wiki'?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, online-resources

I came across [this site](http://www.stringwiki.org/wiki/String_Theory_Wiki) and am wondering if there is a similar page for Mathematics or its sub-areas. Would be very nice if there is one such site which provides 'canonical' references for each sub area and preferably is editable like the Wikipedia system so that it reflects entire community's opinion and not just one person's choices (though the website mentioned above for string theory perhaps does not have this feature). Please provide a link to such a website if it exists.

Comment: If what you're looking for are lists of "canonical" references, how about going to Wikipedia or MathWorld, ignoring the body of the article, and just looking at the list of references at the bottom?

Comment: @RahulNarain Thanks, this is indeed a nice idea. It did not come to my mind before posting the question. However, the idea of having one page with all the sub-area listing and canonical references still looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

As comments have pointed, Wikipedia is already good enough. On the other hand, I agree with the OP that the "String Theory Wiki" web-site provides an interesting form of collecting references and reviews. In my collection of links there is no such a site, and if it does not exist, it certainly should be created one day )))

Nevertheless, there are a few sites of a similar nature, that I'd like to list here as a partial contribution to the answer.

- [The nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/HomePage), "This is a wiki-lab for collaborative work on Mathematics, Physics and Philosophy..."
- [Tricki](http://www.tricki.org/), "a Wiki-style site that is intended to develop into a large store of useful mathematical problem-solving techniques"
- [Pr∞fWiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page), "an online compendium of mathematical proofs"
- [ExWiki](http://exwiki.org/mw/index.php?title=Main_Page), "exercises from various fields of mathematics and computer science"

Hopefully, there are other similar sites, and I'd be glad to hear about them too.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Wikipedia is definitely helpful but a string Wiki type page has the added advantage that all the areas and their sub-areas can be nested in a tree structure. And it would have been great if everybody could have upvoted their favorite books and add short descriptions of strengths and weaknesses of the books (like Amazon.com reviews). By the way, there is another interesting [site](http://xstructure.inr.ac.ru/) but this is for Physics research articles. I wish there were an analogue for Maths (there is AMS MathScinet citation, but I would have preferred a tree like structure).